# Using Minim Match and Bq in SOLR

Tags: solr

I wonder if when using the Bq Parameter, one should take into account what is put in it, in the minimum match clause.

In other words:

1 - I have bq=type:Work^5, which search in the type field, while fq does not contain type. My user search query do not search in type. It searches in other field, but i try to boost, prioritize result by how important is the type of document.

1.1 => I have the feeling that this is another clause that match and therefore, my normal minimum match should take into account that fact. All the query will always match the type field, there is always a type attached to a document. Hence I believe that whatever minimum match I had before, adding the bq parameter means another clause that is matched. My minimum match should be augmented to account for the fact that there is a "type" clause (coming from bq) that will always match

Is that correct ?

I am asking because that seems not to be the case with pf parameter for instance.

Hence i am a bit confused, can someone clarify that for me ?

EDIT1

Here is my query configuration

```
<requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
    <!-- default values for query parameters -->
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="defType">edismax</str>
        <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>

        <!--Minimum 'Should' Match-->
        <!--If there are less than 3 optional clauses, they all must match; for 3 to 5 clauses, one less than the number of clauses must match, for 6 or more clauses, 75% must match, rounded down: "2<-1 5<75%"-->
        <str name="mm">4&lt;-75% 5&lt;50%</str>
        <float name="tie">0.5</float>
        <str name="boost">recip(ms(NOW/DAY,dc.date.issued_tdt),6.33e-11,0.8,0.2)</str>
        <str name="bq">                                                                                                                                                                                                      
          dc.type:"Books"^150                                                                                                                                                                                                
          dc.type:"Annual Reports"^100                                                                                                                                                                                       
          dc.type:"Co-Publications"^70                                                                                                                                                                                       
          dc.type:"Monographs"^50                                                                                                                                                                                            
          dc.type:"Policy Brief"^20                                                                                                                                                                                          
          dc.type:"Technical Notes"^3                                                                                                                                                                                        
          dc.type:"Discussion Papers"^3                                                                                                                                                                                      
          dc.type:"Catalog and Brochure"^1                                                                                                                                                                                   
          dc.type:"Learning Material"^1                                                                                                                                                                                      
          dc.type:"Newsletter/Magazine"                                                                                                                                                                                      
        </str>
```

Comment: can you  update your question and pass your query please? thanks

Comment: It is done as requested see edit1

Comment: So in short, i had to increase my minimum match because of the bq match that counted has one of the match